# Sliding window in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sliding-window

I have a dataframe DF, with two columns A and B shown below:

```
A                    B                  
1                    0             
3                    0               
4                    0                   
2                    1                    
6                    0                    
4                    1                     
7                    1                 
8                    1                     
1                    0
```

A sliding window approach is performed as shown below. The mean is calulated for column B in a sliding window of size 3 sliding by 1 using: rollapply(DF$B, width=3,by=1). The mean values for each window are shown on the left side.

```
    A:         1    3    4    2    6    4    7    8    1                                          
    B:         0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    0                                
              [0    0    0]                                              0
                    [0    0    1]                                        0.33
                          [0    1    0]                                  0.33
                                [1    0    1]                            0.66
                                      [0    1    1]                      0.66
                                            [1    1    1]                1
                                                 [1    1    0]           0.66
output:        0   0.33 0.33 0.66   0.66    1     1    1   0.66
```

Now, for each row/coordinate in column A, all windows containing the coordinate are considered and should retain the highest mean value which gives the results as shown in column 'output'.

I need to obtain the output as shown above. The output should like:

```
A                   B                  Output   
1                   0                      0
3                   0                      0.33
4                   0                      0.33
2                   1                      0.66
6                   0                      0.66
4                   1                      1
7                   1                      1
8                   1                      1
1                   0                    0.66
```

Any help in R?

Comment: (+1) Now I understand the question. Let me try to see if I can figure something out. Just one more thing. I think you lost the final output "mean_A" in this edit. Could you add it as well? Thanks.

Comment: @Arun Now i have added Mean_A.

Comment: is `A` always a sequence 1:N? I don't see how the values in `A` matter to your calculation. It's pretty much `rollmax(rollmean(B,3),3)` so far as I understand it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, not quite. user1779730, check my answer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, Hope the reframed question help to understand the problem

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the patience to *re-read* your question. And it's not recommended to completely re-write the question. In these cases, it's recommended to mark the answer for that question and ask a separate new question.

Comment: More information, also on performance issues, can be found at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/mean-of-a-sliding-window-in-r

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
# form input data
library(zoo)
B <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)

# calculate
k <- 3
rollapply(B, 2*k-1, function(x) max(rollmean(x, k)), partial = TRUE)
```

The last line returns:

```
[1] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000 1.0000000
[8] 1.0000000 0.6666667
```

**If there are `NA` values** you might want to try this:

```
k <- 3
B <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, NA, 1)
rollapply(B, 2*k-1, function(x) max(rollapply(x, k, mean, na.rm = TRUE)), partial = TRUE)
```

where the last line gives this:

```
[1] 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
```

Expanding it out these are formed as:

```
c(mean(B[1:3], na.rm = TRUE), ##
max(mean(B[1:3], na.rm = TRUE), mean(B[2:4], na.rm = TRUE)), ##
max(mean(B[1:3], na.rm = TRUE), mean(B[2:4], na.rm = TRUE), mean(B[3:5], na.rm = TRUE)),
max(mean(B[2:4], na.rm = TRUE), mean(B[3:5], na.rm = TRUE), mean(B[4:6], na.rm = TRUE)),
max(mean(B[3:5], na.rm = TRUE), mean(B[4:6], na.rm = TRUE)), ##
mean(B[4:6], na.rm = TRUE)) ##
```

If you don't want the `k-1` components at each end (marked with `##` above) drop `partial = TRUE`.

Comment: There -- I knew someone would formulate my comment above correctly :-)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks. What is 5 in the rollapply function?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Based on what approximation the width is set to 5? This is just a sample data. Real data has a window size of 5000 that slides by 1.In this case how would we  determine the width of the window?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks a lot for very simple and effective solution. Now it seems we can simulate for any width. One more query, I initially used rollapply(DF$B, width=3,by=1) to calculate the mean of window size 3 sliding by=1 position. But in your solution, there is nothing about the sliding by='' parameter. Can i assume it calculates the mean in the same manner sliding by 1 position?

Comment: There are two length 5 windows. I have deleted my comments since there were getting to be too many and have added some additional info at the end of the answer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck. Hi, i have used the function rollapply(x, 2*k-1, function(x) max(rollmean(x, k)), partial = TRUE)->output with k=5000. The first few values of the output were 0.2730,0.2732,0.2732,0.2734,0.2734... I tried to cross-check by calculating mean(x[1:5000]) which is 0.3538889. But the result from the rollapply function starts from 0.2730. Could you please explain the reason for mis-match of the results?

Comment: Try it with a smaller set of data to verify your understanding. I have shown the correspondence in the case of example data at the end of the post above.  Also note that `rollmean` is not equivalent to `rollapply(..., mean)` in all cases.  `rollmean` does not support `na.rm` and also the sliding window size must be odd for `rollmean` as mentioned in `?rollmean`.  These restrictions were made for sake of speed.

Answer (score 0):

The R library TTR has a number of functions for calculating averages over sliding windows

SMA = simple moving average

```
data$sma <- SMA(data$B, 3)
```

More documentation is here http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/TTR.pdf