# Sliding window on each column of a matrix in R with parallel processing

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing, apply

I have a large matrix with 2000 columns and 3000 rows. For each column, I want to do a sliding window where I sum 15 rows together, then go down one row and sum the next 15, etc... and create a new matrix with this information.  I have a function that works (although seems a bit slow) but would like to run it in parallel, as this is part of a larger script and if I use apply functions without the parallel equivalent the open cluster shuts down. Moreover, I have to do this whole operation 100 times. Later in the script, I use the parLapply or parSapply.

Here is the code I have in a non-parallel fashion:

```
# df is a matrix with 2000 columns and 3000 rows, all numeric and no NAs

size <- 15 # size of window
len <- nrow(df) - size + 1 # number of sliding windows to perform 

sumsmatrix <- apply(df, 2, function(x){
      result <- sapply(1:len, function(y){
      sum(x[y:(y+size-1)])
       })
      return(result)
      })
```

Thanks in advance. 
Ron

Comment: Parallelization should be the last thing you do in speeding up your code.  As a first step, take a look at the function `rollapply` in package `zoo`.  This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943428/sliding-window-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `cumsum`, you won't have to sum the same numbers over again.

```
sumsmatrix <- apply(df, 2, function(x)                   
                     cumsum(x)[size:nrow(df)] - c(0,cumsum(x)[1:(len-1)]))
```

It should be about 100 times faster than what you were doing.

---

Here's how it works:

Let's just say that your `x` is only 5 long, and your window size is 3, to make it easier.

```
x <- 1:5
x
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
cumsum(x)
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15
```

So, the third number of `cumsum(x)` is what you want for the first sum, but the fourth and fifth numbers are too big, because they inlcude the first few numbers as part of the window. So, you just subtract the two.

```
cumsum(x)[3:5]    
# [1] 6 10 15    
cumsum(x)[1:2]
# [1]    1  3
```

But, for the first one you need to subtract zero.

```
cumsum(x)[3:5]    
# [1] 6 10 15    
c(0,cumsum(x)[1:2])
# [1] 0  1  3
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great and very fast... now I just have to figure out how exactly that function works.

Comment: @user3770733 If this answers your question, then you should accept it by clicking the green check box.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrie mentioned, the `zoo` package has some useful moving window functions, such as `rollsum` and `rollapply`. I'm not sure what your OS is, i.e. what parallel packages you are using, but here's a quick example:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
library(zoo)
##
oldD <- matrix(
  sample(1:5, (2000*3000), replace=TRUE),
  ncol=2000)
##
cl <- makeCluster(3,"SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
##
newD <- foreach(j=1:ncol(oldD),
                .combine=cbind,
                .export="rollsum") %dopar% {

                  rollsum(oldD[,j],15)

                }
##
stopCluster(cl)
##
```

Comment: Since "rollsum" is defined in the zoo package, it's better to use `.packages='zoo'` than to export it.