# creating a moving window cumsum in R

Tags: r

Here is a sample df in which I would like to calculate cumulative sum over a moving window.

```
d <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
```

From previous [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388500/sliding-window-on-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-r-with-parallel-processing), I am able to perform a sliding window cumsum, using the following script (thanks to [nograpes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086688/nograpes)):

```
size <- 2 # size of window
len <- nrow(d) - size +1 # number of sliding windows to perform 

sumsmatrix <- apply(d, 2, function(x)                   
  cumsum(x)[size:nrow(d)] - c(0,cumsum(x)[1:(len-1)]))
```

And gives the following output:

```
y
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
```

My request is to perform a cumsum by moving window, instead of sliding. For instance take my window size is 2, I would like to calculate the cumsum of first two rows of a column and then move to the 3rd and calculate for 3rd and 4th and so on ..

Desired output:

```
y
1
3
3
7
5
11
7
15
9
19
```

How can I tweak the script to suit my needs?

Answer (score 1):

We can do a group by operation by creating a grouping variable with `%/%` and then use on the group by functions i.e. `tapply`

```
unlist(tapply(d$y, (seq_len(nrow(d))-1)%/% size, FUN = cumsum), use.names = FALSE)
#[1]  1  3  3  7  5 11  7 15  9 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to create a group variable and use `cumsum()`.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
group_by(group = rep(1:(nrow(.)/2), each = 2)) %>%
transmute(y = cumsum(y)) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-group)

#       y
#   <int>
#1      1
#2      3
#3      3
#4      7
#5      5
#6     11
#7      7
#8     15
#9      9
#10    19
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial example seems to be for a rolling sum over a window of width 2, not a cumulative sum.  It can be written more compactly as:

```
library(zoo)

rollapplyr(d, 2, sum)
```

or

```
rollsum(d, 2)
```

or this which uses no packages:

```
apply(d, 2, function(x) rowSums(embed(x, 2)))
```

Now getting to the actual question here are some alternatives:

**1) zoo** To perform a `cumsum` rolling forward by 2 at a time:

```
apply(d, 2, function(x) t(rollapplyr(x, 2, cumsum, by = 2)))
```

**2) no packages** This would also work and uses no packages:

```
apply(d, 2, function(x) apply(matrix(x, 2), 2, cumsum))
```

**Revised** to work on every column of its input.